# Merge multidimensional array of hash based on hash key and value in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, multidimensional-array, hash

I have one array and i want to match value of `id` key with other array of hash in multidimensional array,

```
input = [ 
  [ {"id"=>"1","name"=>"a"},
    {"id"=>"2","name"=>"b"},
    {"id"=>"3","name"=>"c"},
    {"id"=>"4","name"=>"d"},
    {"id"=>"5","name"=>"e"},
    {"id"=>"6","name"=>"f"}
  ],
  [ {"id"=>"3","hoby"=>"AA"},
    {"id"=>"3","hoby"=>"BB"},
    {"id"=>"1","hoby"=>"CC"},
    {"id"=>"1","hoby"=>"DD"},
    {"id"=>"4","hoby"=>"EE"}
  ],
  [ {"id"=>"1","language"=>"A"},
    {"id"=>"1","language"=>"B"},
    {"id"=>"2","language"=>"B"},
    {"id"=>"2","language"=>"C"},
    {"id"=>"6","language"=>"D"}
  ] 
]
```

I need array output like,

```
output = [ 
  {"id"=>"1","name"=>"a","id"=>"1","hoby"=>"CC","id"=>"1","language"=>"A","id"=>"1","language"=>"B"},
  {"id"=>"2","name"=>"b","id"=>"2","language"=>"B"},
  {"id"=>"3","name"=>"c","id"=>"3","hoby"=>"AA","id"=>"3","hoby"=>"BB"},
  {"id"=>"4","name"=>"d","id"=>"4","hoby"=>"EE"},
  {"id"=>"5","name"=>"e"},
  {"id"=>"6","name"=>"f","id"=>"6","language"=>"D"}
]
```

I have wrote code for this,

```
len = input.length - 1
output = []
input[0].each do |value,index|
  for i in 1..len
    input[i].each do |j|
      if value["id"] == j["id"]
        output << value.merge(j)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

But i am getting wrong output array.There might be any number of sub array in multidimensional array.

Thank,

Comment: for `id = 1` there are multiple hobbies. Which `hobby` will get precedence?

Comment: You need to add more information about your requirements: people are just guessing what you want since what you have asked for is not a valid data structure.  If I was you I would take a step back and describe the problem you are trying to solve rather than say "how to i turn this data into that data?".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe this can help you.

```
input = [
  [
  {"id"=>"1","name"=>"a"},
  {"id"=>"2","name"=>"b"},
  {"id"=>"3","name"=>"c"},
  {"id"=>"4","name"=>"d"},
  {"id"=>"5","name"=>"e"},
  {"id"=>"6","name"=>"f"}
  ],
  [
  {"id"=>"3","hoby"=>"AA"},
  {"id"=>"3","hoby"=>"BB"},
  {"id"=>"1","hoby"=>"CC"},
  {"id"=>"1","hoby"=>"DD"},
  {"id"=>"4","hoby"=>"EE"}
  ],
  [
  {"id"=>"1","language"=>"A"},
  {"id"=>"1","language"=>"B"},
  {"id"=>"2","language"=>"B"},
  {"id"=>"2","language"=>"C"},
  {"id"=>"6","language"=>"D"}
  ]
]
```

This way you can make your "sort" results.

```
output = {}
input.flatten.each do |h|
  output[h["id"]] = {} unless output[h["id"]]
  output[h["id"]].merge!(h)
end

output.values
# => [
# =>   {"id"=>"1", "name"=>"a", "hoby"=>"DD", "language"=>"B"},
# =>   {"id"=>"2", "name"=>"b", "language"=>"C"},
# =>   {"id"=>"3", "name"=>"c", "hoby"=>"BB"},
# =>   {"id"=>"4", "name"=>"d", "hoby"=>"EE"},
# =>   {"id"=>"5", "name"=>"e"},
# =>   {"id"=>"6", "name"=>"f", "language"=>"D"}
# => ]
```

**But the better way is use Hash in input. You can define input like hash and "id" like key so if you generate the data, you dont have problem to sort it.**

Someting like this

```
{
  "1" => {"name" => "a", "hoby" => "DD", "language" => "B"}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all - it is impossible to have two elements in a hash with the same key. When assigning the value to some key will make the next assignment of the same key with new value override the previous one.

Let's consider the example:

```
hash = {}
hash["id"] = 1
hash["id"] = 3
hash["id"] = 5
```

What output for `hash["id"]` would you expect? `1`, `3`, `5` or maybe `[1, 3, 5]`? [The way the Hash in ruby works](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html) it will output `5`, because this is the last assignment to unique key.

Having said that, it is impossible to store multiple occurrences in your hash, but you can try processing it with something like:

```
input.flatten
     .group_by { |h| h["id"] }
     .map do |k, a| 
       a.each_with_object({}) { |in_h, out_h| out_h.merge!(in_h) } 
     end
```

Which will result with hash like:

```
[{"id"=>"1", "name"=>"a", "hoby"=>"DD", "language"=>"B"}, 
 {"id"=>"2", "name"=>"b", "language"=>"C"}, 
 {"id"=>"3", "name"=>"c", "hoby"=>"BB"}, 
 {"id"=>"4", "name"=>"d", "hoby"=>"EE"}, 
 {"id"=>"5", "name"=>"e"}, 
 {"id"=>"6", "name"=>"f", "language"=>"D"}]
```

Well, it is not the hash as you would expect, but at least it might put you in some direction.

Hope that helps!